# Guardar modelo con campo ManyToManyField usando CreateView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo dos modelos uno `Temas` y otro `Videos` tienen una relación mucho a muchos ya
que un `Video` puede tratar diferentes `Temas`, el problema esta que a la hora de guardar un `Video` no me da ningún error y se me guarda pero sin los temas que e elegido con un `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, ademas de que el campo `Temas` no me lo valida y estoy declarándolo `required` en el formulario, lo mas extraño es que usando el admin de Django si se almacenan todos los campos incluidos los `ManytoManyField`.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Tema(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#007bff')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def get_html_badge(self):
        name = escape(self.nombre)
        color = escape(self.color)
        html = '<span class="badge badge-primary" style="background-color: %s">%s</span>' % (color, name)
        return mark_safe(html)

class Video(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dueño = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d')
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tema = models.ManyToManyField(Tema, related_name='video_tema',blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s ' % (self.nombre)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class VideoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Video
    form_class = VideoAdd

    template_name = 'Lab/video_add_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        video = form.save(commit=False)
        video.dueño = self.request.user

        video.save()
        messages.info(self.request, 'El video fue añadido satisfactoriamente')
        return redirect('add_video')
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class VideoAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    tema = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Tema.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=True,
       )

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('docfile', "nombre", 'descripcion','tema')
```

Comment: Como dices en el comentario, lo que notaba era la ausencia del `save_m2m` debes agregarla para que se guarde, porque estás cambiando el funcionamiento por defecto del método `form_valid`. Si aún así no funciona, lo que deberías probar sería validar la cantidad de temas que se escogen en el formulario, y eso puedes hacerlo desde el método `clean` o `clean_tema` del formulario, así te aseguras que los datos están llegando y que siempre tendrás temas en tus vídeos. Porque aunque sea ManyToMany y required, puede pasar el formulario y no arrojar error si no pones un tema

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el formulario. Como tienes la clase `VideoAdd` está sobreescribiendo la variable tema y reemplazandola por la variable que tienes creada. La forma más fácil para sobreescribir la manera que tiene Django de mostrar los campos es usando la variable `widgets = {'campo': forms.TipoCampo()}`

De esta manera tu clase ModelForm quedaría de esta manera:

```
class VideoAdd(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Video
    fields = ('docfile', "nombre", 'descripcion','tema')    
    widgets = {
        'tema': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }
```

Comment: No eso ya lo probe y nada sigue igual buscando en la documentacion hablan de la funcion save_m2m() que es necesario usarla cuando usas commit=False y ahi campos many-to-many,